# Android DatePicker shows wrong value of month and disable past and date not working for appointment

Tags: android, android-datepicker

For example, if I select December (the 12th month), then it returns 12−1=11.

```
final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String dDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + (7));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question one by one:

**1. Android Date Picker show the wrong value of month**

From [Calendar.MONTH](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#MONTH) documentation

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
> calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
> and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
> number of months in a year.

So the first month (January) is 0 and the last month (December) is 11. That explains why when you select December, the date picker returns 11.

**2. Disable past and date not working for appointment**

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + (7));
```

I guess you want to set max date is 7 days after today, but the code you wrote is set max date is 7 milliseconds from today, that why you see the date picker disable all dates except today.

Change your code to:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // Add 7 days after today
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```